# My object seems to get deleted, with me requesting that. EXEC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I create an array of custom objects called players.

```
@interface Player : NSObject 
{
    NSString *name;
    NSNumber *spd;
    NSNumber *atk;
    NSNumber *def;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *spd;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *atk;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *def;

@end

#import "Player.h"


@implementation Player

@synthesize name;
@synthesize spd;
@synthesize atk;
@synthesize def;

@end
```

That seems ok.

So I have a function that setups an array full of Player objects.

```
-(void) initTheGame
{
    NSLog(@" initTheGame");

    playerArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    p1Cards =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    p2Cards =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        Player  *myPlayer = [[Player alloc] init];
        myPlayer.name =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Name%d", (rand()%99)];
        myPlayer.spd = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:(rand() % 100)]; 
        myPlayer.atk = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:(rand() % 100)]; 
        myPlayer.def = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:(rand() % 100)]; 
        [playerArray addObject:myPlayer];       
        [myPlayer autorelease];     
    }

    [self dealHands];
    [self setupValuesForUI];

}
```

It works as expected. Fills up the array full of Player objects containing random data.

```
-(void) setupValuesForUI
{
    NSLog(@"setupValuesForUI"); 

    Player *p1 = [[Player alloc] init];
    p1 = [playerArray objectAtIndex:0];

    p1Name.text = p1.name;
    [p1Speed setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Spd: %@",[p1.spd stringValue] ] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [p1Attack setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Atk: %@",[p1.atk stringValue] ] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [p1Defense setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Def: %@",[p1.def stringValue] ] forState:UIControlStateNormal];    

    [p1 autorelease];

}
```

This function uses some IBOutlets to set the Text values for a Lable and 3 Buttons. All work ok they display there data.

Now when i press a button and an IBAction method gets called my app crashes out with an 
EXEC_BAD_ACCESS

The code hasnt changed, I try and access the object in the same way, but it seems to have disappeared. :(

Can somebody explain what I did wrong. I'm a newbie to Objective C so forgive me if this is
an obvious problem to you. I can find it after hours of trying to debug it.

```
-(IBAction) spd
{

    Player *p1 = [[Player alloc] init];
    p1 = [playerArray objectAtIndex:0];
    int x = [p1.spd integerValue];  // this line crashes out the app
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the `[p1 autorelease];` from the `setupValuesForUI` function. Since you did not `alloc` or `retain` it in this method, then there is no need to `release` it.

PS. you should use `[myPlayer release];` and not `[myPlayer autorelease];` in `initTheGame` just as a better coding practice.

Comment: The advice is slightly wrong.  As well as removing `[p1 autorelease]`, `Player *p1 = [[Player alloc] init];` needs to go too because it is never used.  In fact it is overwritten and leaks straight away.

Comment: JeremyP is right, make sure you remove the `Player *p1 = [[Player alloc] init];`

Answer (score 0):

This place has errors.

```
-(void) setupValuesForUI
{
    NSLog(@"setupValuesForUI"); 

    Player *p1 = [[Player alloc] init];
    p1 = [playerArray objectAtIndex:0];

    ....
    [p1 autorelease];

}
```